# How to implement search feature?

Tags: javascript, php, android, mysql

I have a field keywords in my table which stores all the comma separated keywords.
Now, i have an input word and i want to search all the items from the table matching that input using the keywords fields in the table. Is there a better way to do it or the only way is by linear search over  whole table.

Comment: All you need to do is search all the items from the table matching that input using the keywords fields in the table.

Comment: *a field keywords in my table which stores all the comma separated keywords* Normalize it to `(keyword_group_id, ordinal_position, one_keyword)`.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton yes i get it but i was asking is there any other way

Comment: @Akina can you elaborate more please. Using an example if possible

Comment: @dhruvtailor How should we know? You need to provide more details. Break down the structure of relevant tables, give us sample data, example searches, example expected returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### An example.

Now you have a storage which looks like:

```
group_id | keywords
-----------------------------------------
   ...   |  ...
   123   |  word1,word2,word3
   124   |  word5,word2
   125   |  word3,word4,word1,word7,word8
   ...   |  ...
```

You convert it to

```
group_id | ordinal | keyword
----------------------------
   ...       ...     ...
   123        1      word1
   123        2      word2
   123        3      word3
   124        1      word5
   124        2      word2
   125        1      word3
   125        2      word4
   125        3      word1
   125        4      word7
   125        5      word8
   ...       ...     ...
```

When you need group identifier for groups which contains, for example, `'word2'`, you execute

```
SELECT group_id 
FROM keywords
WHERE keyword = 'word2'
```

which will return

```
group_id
--------
  123
  124
```

And when you need the whole keywords groups you execute

```
SELECT group_id, GROUP_CONCAT(group_id ORDER BY ordinal) keywords
FROM keywords
JOIN ( SELECT group_id 
       FROM keywords 
       WHERE keyword = 'word2' ) AS groups USING (group_id)
```

which will return

```
group_id | keywords
-------------------------------
   123   |  word1,word2,word3
   124   |  word5,word2
```

To improve the performance you'd create proper indices (by `(keyword, group_id)` and by `(group_id)`) in table structure.

Comment: I would be tempted to move your linking structure to a many-to-many where you can store the original table ID, the ordinal position and the word ID (PK on both IDs). Then your word table could have a unique index on the word, speeding up the searches.

Comment: @Skrrp This is true if a keyword is in sync for all groups it is mentioned in (altering in one group must alter it in all another groups) otherwise the above structure is more safe.

Comment: ah, I see where you are coming from. I would personally have treated the words as immutable and not 'belonging' to any of the records on the left table. So if someone 'deletes' a word, it drops the m2m. If a word is 'edited' then the m2m is dropped and re-created to the new word (whether it was inserted, or already there).

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to recommend using a dedicated search index. Akina's answer is great for doing this totally inside MySQL. If you want to match `Dave` on `like '%ave%'` though, you need to read up on `FULLTEXT` indices; [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html).

With this structure though, you have just built half a search index. It would be better for you to introduce a real search index into your stack. Elastic is really easy to implement these days with libraries for Laravel and Symfony, or just with the PHP driver (some assembly required). Once you have a search index it will then provide extra benefits such as auto-pluralise searches and will even return your results ordered by match score.

All you would need to do is create a search index containing one field and space-separate all your words into it for each record in your MySQL database. Your Elastic record would then look like this:

```
{
    "_id": "[Elastic's record ID]",
    "mysql_id": "[Your ID in MySQL]",
    "search_field": "word1 word2 word3"
}
```

Searching this index will return you the MySQL IDs for the search, which you can then hydrate back in your PHP application.